# How to download a jar file from ansible

Tags: java, bash, amazon-web-services, ansible, devops

I want to download a jar by using ansible. I want to write a play books to download a jar file.help me out. 
How to download a jar file by using ansible code?

Comment: This is way too broad for a question on SO. Start experimenting on your side and edit your question with more precise info once you have tried something.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want.

playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
   - name: download jar
     get_url:
       url: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/apache//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.6-bin.tar.gz
       dest: ./commons-io-2.6-bin.tar.gz
```

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Comment: Is this the answer for you want?